# Authenticate Github to Google Cloud Platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, github-actions, google-cloud-pubsub

I have built an app that works locally as well as deployed on CloudRun.
I am running a workflow in github as part of my CI/CD.

Currently, the test fail because Github is not authenticated
This code
  `publisher = pubsub_v1.PublisherClient()`
triggers

`google.auth.exceptions.DefaultCredentialsError: File *** was not found.`

```
/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.13/x64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/cloud/pubsub_v1/publisher/client.py:139: in __init__
    super().__init__(**kwargs)
/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.13/x64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/pubsub_v1/services/publisher/client.py:492: in __init__
    self._transport = Transport(
/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.13/x64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/pubsub_v1/services/publisher/transports/grpc.py:153: in __init__
    super().__init__(
/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.13/x64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/pubsub_v1/services/publisher/transports/base.py:104: in __init__
    credentials, _ = google.auth.default(
/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.13/x64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/auth/_default.py:615: in default
    credentials, project_id = checker()
/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.13/x64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/auth/_default.py:608: in <lambda>
    lambda: _get_explicit_environ_credentials(quota_project_id=quota_project_id),
/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.13/x64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/auth/_default.py:228: in _get_explicit_environ_credentials
    credentials, project_id = load_credentials_from_file(
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 

filename = '***'
scopes = None, default_scopes = None, quota_project_id = None, request = None

    def load_credentials_from_file(
        filename, scopes=None, default_scopes=None, quota_project_id=None, request=None
    ):
        """Loads Google credentials from a file.
    
        The credentials file must be a service account key, stored authorized
        user credentials, external account credentials, or impersonated service
        account credentials.
    
        Args:
            filename (str): The full path to the credentials file.
            scopes (Optional[Sequence[str]]): The list of scopes for the credentials. If
                specified, the credentials will automatically be scoped if
                necessary
            default_scopes (Optional[Sequence[str]]): Default scopes passed by a
                Google client library. Use 'scopes' for user-defined scopes.
            quota_project_id (Optional[str]):  The project ID used for
                quota and billing.
            request (Optional[google.auth.transport.Request]): An object used to make
                HTTP requests. This is used to determine the associated project ID
                for a workload identity pool resource (external account credentials).
                If not specified, then it will use a
                google.auth.transport.requests.Request client to make requests.
    
        Returns:
            Tuple[google.auth.credentials.Credentials, Optional[str]]: Loaded
                credentials and the project ID. Authorized user credentials do not
                have the project ID information. External account credentials project
                IDs may not always be determined.
    
        Raises:
            google.auth.exceptions.DefaultCredentialsError: if the file is in the
                wrong format or is missing.
        """
        if not os.path.exists(filename):
>           raise exceptions.DefaultCredentialsError(
                "File {} was not found.".format(filename)
            )
E           google.auth.exceptions.DefaultCredentialsError: File *** was not found.

/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.13/x64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/auth/_default.py:116: DefaultCredentialsError
```

I have followed this part of the [tutorial](https://github.com/google-github-actions/auth?tab=readme-ov-file#preferred-direct-workload-identity-federation), setting the action to authenticate Github as the first steps of the workflow

Step 5 of the tutorial seems to be the step where access is actually granted to resoures but the example is too specific. So the issue persists.
I am using Pub/Sub, what should the command it be ?

Comment: 1) Regarding the error `File *** was not found`. More details on that file are required. Did you set `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`? Don't set that environment variable. Include the code that generated the error. 2) For Step 5, what do you mean by `the example is too specific`? If you mean you don't know what to use for Pub/Sub, that would depend on how you are using Pub/Sub. Typically you would use `roles/pubsub.publisher` or `roles/pubsub.subscriber`. The [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/access-control#roles) has more information. 3) Edit your question with more details

Comment: I edited the question. Based on the comments, I'm guessing I need to do something along the lines of ```gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding  ${PROJECT_ID} \
  --role="roles/roles/pubsub.publisher" \
  --member="principalSet://iam.googleapis.com/${WORKLOAD_IDENTITY_POOL_ID}/attribute.repository/${REPO}"```.
But I get ```ERROR: Policy modification failed. For a binding with condition, run "gcloud alpha iam policies lint-condition" to identify issues in condition.``` so not sure I'm doing this right

Comment: To publish I think the command should be `gcloud pubsub topics add-iam-policy-binding` [link](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/pubsub/topics/add-iam-policy-binding). However, `principalSet` is not listed as a supported principal.

Comment: Note: you still have a credentials error regarding that file.

Comment: Put back the link to the documentation that you are using. [link](https://github.com/google-github-actions/auth?tab=readme-ov-file#preferred-direct-workload-identity-federation).

Comment: In the Google Cloud Console GUI go to `IAM & Admin` -> `Workload Identity Federation`. Is that set up?

Comment: Yes, I see the pool I created while following the [.README](https://github.com/google-github-actions/auth?tab=readme-ov-file#preferred-direct-workload-identity-federation) and it is enabled

Comment: Indeed, the command you link for granting publish rights to a topic could work. At least it's clearer what it does to me. But yes I get ```ERROR: (gcloud.pubsub.topics.add-iam-policy-binding) INVALID_ARGUMENT: Invalid principalSet member```

Comment: Since `principalSet` is not supported, my suggestion is to use the service account method [link](https://github.com/google-github-actions/auth?tab=readme-ov-file#workload-identity-federation-through-a-service-account).

Comment: I managed to make it work. Thank you for your help !

Comment: Which method did you get working? Can you provide details on the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `principalSet` is not listed as a supported principal of `gcloud pubsub topics add-iam-policy-binding`, I had to use the service account [method](https://github.com/google-github-actions/auth?tab=readme-ov-file#workload-identity-federation-through-a-service-account)

I replaced the last step by

`gcloud secrets add-iam-policy-binding "my-secret" \ --project="${PROJECT_ID}" \ --role="roles/pubsub.publisher" \ --member="serviceAccount:my-service-account@${PROJECT_ID}.iam.gserviceaccount.com"`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are trying to grant Workload Identity token, the step 5 could potentially be:

```
gcloud pubsub topics add-iam-policy-binding TOPIC --member=PRINCIPAL --role=ROLE
```

See SDK doc [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/pubsub/topics/add-iam-policy-binding)